# How do I instantiate an Object after another set of objects and place it in between

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate an object after a set of objects are moved a certain distance. In my code I am making walls and what I'me looking to do is create 2 poles, drag my mouse and create a wall in between the poles, this much I have. What I want to follow is if the distance between the 2 poles is exceeded the first wall stay's in place and added to an index and a new wall is instantiate between the first wall and the end pole.

```
void adjustWall()
{
    //start and end pole look at each other
    startPole.transform.LookAt(endPole.transform.position);
    endPole.transform.LookAt(startPole.transform.position);
    //gets the distance between the start and end poles
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(startPole.transform.position, endPole.transform.position);
    //places the wall between the 2 poles, rotates it to face both of them and scales it between them.
    wall.transform.position = startPole.transform.position + distance / 2 * startPole.transform.forward;
    wall.transform.rotation = endPole.transform.rotation;
    //wall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(wall.transform.localScale.x, wall.transform.localScale.y, distance); 
    if (distance > 10)
    {
        //if the distance is greater than 10, set wall, add it to an index then instaniate a new wall between that wall and the end poll. Do this Once until it's time to create a new wall.
    }
}
```

adjustWall is called in my Update function.

Comment: what framework is this? unity3d?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are asking for? Would you like to instantiate a new prefab when the distance is great than 10?

Comment: Yes Unity 3D and the distance is greater than 10 I would like to instantiate a new prefab. Thanks.

Comment: How about just build the wall in increments that cannot exceed 10?  Using modular math, you can find the number of 10-length walls you need, then fill the remainder with a shorter wall.  A good candidate for a loop.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and I would do it if these wall's dimensions weren't so weird.

Answer (score 0):

**Instantiating Prefabs at runtime**
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

```
public GameObject prefab;

// ...

if (distance > 10)
{
    // Calculate your target position
    Vector3 pos;

    // Instantiate the wall's GO
    var wall = Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
}
```